# Does this argument rely on countable choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Consider the following

> **Theorem:** Any algebraic field extension $K|F$ of infinite degree contains finite subextensions of arbitrarily high degree.
>
> **Proof:** We'll prove that, for any n, there's a finite subextension $F_n|F$ of degree $\geq 2^n$, by induction on n.
>
> The case $n=1$ is obvious. Suppose, by inductive hypothesis, that we
>   have a finite subextension $F_{n-1}|F$ of degree $\geq 2^{n-1}$. Since
>   $K|F$ is an infinite extension, there's an element $x\in K\setminus F_{n-1}$,
>   which is algebraic over $F$; then $F_{n-1}(x)|F$ is a finite
>   extension of degree $\geq 2^n$, as we wanted.

Does this rely on countable choice? Note that for each fixed $n$, we have only made a finite number of choices to get the desired subextension.

Comment: Choice is true.

Comment: This will probably fit into one of the algebra related tags as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is really just induction with finitely many choices.

The axioms of choice would come in if you would have wanted to say there is a countably infinite set of algebraically independent elements. With this proof, you would invoke Dependent Choice, which is stronger than countable choice. But I reckon the proof can be slightly modified to use just countable choice instead.

Comment: What would be the slight modification?

Comment: Consider $A_n$ to be the set of $n$-tuples of algebraically independent elements. Your proof shows no $A_n$ is empty; now choose one tuple from each set, then mesh them together and remove redundant elements by induction on the lexicographic order you find there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Asaf.